# Redux connect and mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to understand how redux' connect works I was wondering if it:

1. creates a new component everytime the state changes with new props
   or
2. update the existing component's state

If it's the latter doesn't this go against React's philosophy of immutable props? 
How does it update the props?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React's philosophy of immutable props means you are not supposed to update props from inside the component itself. You can pass new property values to a component from the parent component. That's why there exists a componentWillReceiveProps method.

Basically a react component receives props and renders HTML. A component *can* use local state but if you use Redux this is usually not needed.
Redux manages all the state in a single state object and using the connect method you can 'connect' a part of the global Redux state to a react component. It will then be available as props inside that component.

So to answer your question: neither answer 1 nor 2 is correct.
When using connect to connect a piece of state to you component it will pass that state as props. You component will have no state (unless you write your own local state), only props. These props get updated if the corresponding part of the redux state changes.

Comment: That you for your quick answer. So since I'm integrating React in an existing app and Redux is not an option for now, what would be the proper way to mimick the updating of the props from outside the component?

Comment: Wherever you render a react component you can pass dynamic props (ie from a vaiable). Whenever the props change the following methods of your component will get called in this order:

1) `componentWillReceiveProps()`
2) `shouldComponentUpdate()`
3) `componentWillUpdate()`
4) `render()`
5) `componentDidUpdate()`

You only need the render method for basic components.

Comment: If I understand you properly you "Create a new component" in your render method and if it's an existing one react will simply update it's props?

Comment: Every time a component receives new props and gets rerendered the output HTML of the render method gets compared to the HTML in the DOM and only the difference will get updated in the DOM.

I recommend you read this page of the react documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: @MaloGuertin Yes, Exactly. React maintains a virtual DOM. So everytime prop or state changes, react's diff algorithm will run and if the component is present in the DOM it will just update it. You may find reading this helpful. [React Diff algorithm](https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2013/diff/)

Comment: If my answer helped you out please mark it as best answer :)